# Getting "Authorization has been denied for this request." when attempting to create a channel in Teams

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am getting this rather unhelpful error and it seems to occur for a large variety of things based on the SO posts. So here I am.

I went here https://apps.dev.microsoft.com, logged in and created a new App. I generated a secret and stored it for later on a post-it note... I granted "Group.ReadWrite.All" under "Delegate" as the [create channel API doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_post_channels) says I should. I left everything else in the App as default.

I then do a token request like so:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
"https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANT/oauth2/v2.0/token" \
-d "client_id=$APP_ID" -d "scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default" \
-d "client_secret=$PASSWORD" -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

which gives me this mess:

```
{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"ext_expires_in":0,"access_token":"BIG_LONG_TOKEN"}
```

I then take that token and stuff it into my Authorization header and make the call to create the channel:

```
curl "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/$TENANT/channels" \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $BIG_LONG_TOKEN" \
-d '{
  "displayName": "mynewchannel",
  "description": "Channel Description"
}'
```

But this results in tears and this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "Authorization has been denied for this request.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "c572f6df-7537-4a53-aefc-fcc8c71e2037",
      "date": "2018-04-17T23:46:50"
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure what I'm missing, but hopefully it's obvious to someone else...

EDIT: Interestingly, if I set TOKEN to garbage, I get a more helpful answer, but this indicates my TOKEN is at least mostly ok and it is more of a authorization rather than an authentication issue

```
TOKEN=garbage
curl -X GET "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/$TENANT/channels" -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
```

Results in

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "166cb22b-c135-45e9-9f23-0e73bc68475d",
      "date": "2018-04-18T00:20:47"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please try this in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and let me know if it works for you?

Comment: Same response body, but there is a message `Failure - Status Code 401, 562msLooks like you may not have the permissions for this call. Please modify your permissions.` I am authenticated in the Explorer. I verified I can create a new channel through the teams.microsoft.com UI.

Answer (score 1):

> I went here https://apps.dev.microsoft.com, logged in and created a new App. I generated a secret and stored it for later on a post-it note...

According to [Create Channel Rest API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_post_channels) document, Application type permission is not supported. So you get the error information `Authorization has been denied for this request`.

> Delegated permissions are used by apps that **have a signed-in user present**. For these apps either the user or an administrator consents to the permissions that the app requests and the app is delegated permission to act as the signed-in user when making calls to Microsoft Graph. Some delegated permissions can be consented to by non-administrative users, but some higher-privileged permissions require administrator consent.

As  Wajeed - MSFT mentioned that you could use [Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) with your account login to have a try.

**Note:**  APIs under the **/beta versio**n in Microsoft Graph are in preview and are subject to change. Use of these APIs **in production applications is not** **supported**.